# differentiable functions and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble understanding where to start with the following question:

Let $F$ be the set of all differentiable functions on $[a,b]$. Show $F$ is a vector space with the standard operations.

So I know that I need to prove the axioms, however I don't have a function to start with. How do I represent $F$ as a set of differentiable functions so I can prove the axioms?

Thanks.

Comment: your vectors are the functions,  your scalars are elements of the field you're working on.  So,  take arbitrary vectors (functions) and scalars, and show the vector space properties hold

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions, and $a$ is a Real number. What is $f+g$? What about $af+g$? You don't need to be given any particular functions, you can imagine any two functions in $F$ and show how $F$ is a vector space using two arbitrary functions.

Comment: I hope everything comes out ok.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $(af(x)+bg(x))'=af'(x)+bg'(x)$ and your vectors are $f$ and $g$.
You can omit verifying all axioms, because $F$ is a subspace of $C[a,b]$ (continuous functions).

Comment: The way I understand it is that you prove VA and SM for subspaces, but when proving a vector space you need to prove all axioms. The question states that F is the vector space, however you've said that F is a subspace of C[a,b]. Could you please explain the relevance of a subspace in this question? Thanks.

Comment: @Angie01 If you know, that $F$ is a subset of $C[a,b]$, you must only verify that multiplying a vector by a scalar is in $F$, and sum of vectors is in $F$, which is verified by the first equation in my answer.  I am assuming that you are not expected to verify all conditions of the linear space, but you may use this characterization of a linear subspace.

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer now:

Take two functions f(x), g(x) $\in$ F, which are differentiable.

$(f(x)+g(x))' = f'(x) +g'(x) \in [a,b]$ as for a function to be differentiable, it must be continuous over a given interval.

let c $\in$ $R$,

$(cf(x))'=cf'(x) \in [a,b]$ as f(x) is continous on $[a,b]$

I don't really see how this is proving much - it's just rehashing the axioms with different notation.